How to join 2x4's in the long dimension
I'm going to be building a chicken coop and my design entails the walls having 2x4's put together in the long dimension, unlike normal wall studs (see picture). I'd like to try to avoid the precision cuts required for the solution in the picture though. My fallback is to toenail some screws but I'd like to hear if people have better options?  If toenailing, are there best practices to get them right and to get a nice countersink?


There's an entire vernacular architecture of how to easily build things with 2x4 framing, and this sort of thing is NEVER seen in it. Vernaculars develop because they work. Things like this have a tendency to fail spectacularly and thus don't end up in the vernacular. Do your chickens a favor and follow normal framing practices that are known to work.

If you must: Lap joints, bridle joints, joining plates. Screws/nails are not intended to take structural load, just to hold wood in alignment do it can carry the load. Don't reinvent; look at the hundreds of plans available.

I don't see any coop designs with walls built in the fashion of a framed house.  e.g. https://www.walmart.com/ip/Gymax-Wooden-Chicken-Coop-Outdoor-Indoor-Small-Rabbit-Hutch-w-Run-Grey/246371494

This one is framed like a house but is pretty intense compared to the little thing I have in mind: https://www.lancasterchickencoops.com/images/chicken_coops/Quaker-6x10-Combination-Chicken-Coop-In-Stock-f2.jpg

A biscuit joiner can be used to put two or three #20 biscuits into the joint. That might suffice for a simple coop.

why not just buy longer 2x4s

How large of a coop are you building? My local lumberyard can supply 16 foot 2x4s, if expect yours can too. Is your coop wider than that?

@Jasen Note I'm trying to make a 90 degree turn, not just make long 2x4s out of short.

is that your saw in the photo?

You might be able to use something called a “truss gang nail plate” that looks something like this:

They are used all the time to join trusses in the flat plane.
Good luck!
